# Why do I have an extra hard drive?

Tags: mac, encryption, diskutil

When I go to "About this Mac" it shows I have 1 500GB hard drive, but when I use diskutil list it shows I have 2 500GB. Can someone explain this please?

My USB drive says its encrypted in diskutil which is correct, but my main drive that has Mac OS on it should also be encrypted (that's the way I set it up when install Mac OS), but it doesn't say it in diskutil and it says "encrtpted" for the USB. How can I tell if my hard drive is encrypted or not?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing the listing for both the logical volume and the physical disk on which that logical volume resides - note the Apple_APFS container ***disk1*** matches the APFS container scheme Identifier ***disk1*** - lines 6, 7, & 10 of your output from diskutil.

Suggest you look in the GUI version of disk util to get a sense of physical disk and logical volume - I think that will make it clearer for you:

[image]

[image]

[image]

hope this helps mate.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. It makes the hard drive configuration clearer.